# Magento products stubbornly using old theme

Tags: theme, cache, products, parent-child-theme, theme-fallback

I'm trying to change the package+theme for a magento installation.

- The old theme is at `default/paws`
- The new theme is at `ebajes/default`

While the rest of the views (home page, categories, etc.) have been changed to the new one, the products are still being shown with the old theme

I have tried :

- making a change in admin system > design
- setting the value of "package" and "template" in system > config > design
- setting custom display of the supercategory of all products
- setting custom display for specific categories

I even tried renaming the entire default/paws folder, but its now falling back to the `default/default` theme.

Where should this change be made? The caches are disabled.

Comment: unlikely, but you don't have a custom design set on all the products?

Comment: @andrewkett No there is no theme set on any product. Yet, explicitly setting it to the desired theme, works. There is also some level of randomness in whether a page renders as old or new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find the reason why it was acting funny, but I got it solved by :

- Manage Products → Select all
- Edit properties
- Set custom layout to the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this as well.  Do you have GT Optimizer installed?  I suspect that is the issue for me.

My workaround is to use System->Design.  On this page use 'Add Custom Design'.  Select your theme, set the start day in the past, and do not set an end date.  This has forced the theme on all my pages.

Comment: I did that, but it worked for everything else, except product pages.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works not allways first time:

My workaround is to use System->Design. On this page use 'Add Custom Design'. Select your theme, set the start day in the past, and do not set an end date. This has forced the theme on all my pages.

But doing this more times, it solves the problem!